# ios How to add UIImage to UITextView asynchronous?

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, uiimage, uitextview

I can add image asynchronously seperately by using **UIImageView+AFNetworking**

`[imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.data valueForKey:@"image_link"]]];`

I can also add image to UITextView by

```
UITextView *text = [[UITextView alloc] init];
UIImageView *imageView = [UIImageView new];
[imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
CGRect aRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 125, 120);
[imageView setFrame:aRect];

UIBezierPath *exclusionPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:aRect];
text.textContainer.exclusionPaths = @[exclusionPath];
[text addSubview:imageView];
```

But I cannot add image asynchronously in UITextView like

```
UITextView *text = [[UITextView alloc] init];
UIImageView *imageView = [UIImageView new];
[imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.data valueForKey:@"image_link"]]];
CGRect aRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 125, 120);
[imageView setFrame:aRect];
UIBezierPath *exclusionPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:aRect];
text.textContainer.exclusionPaths = @[exclusionPath];
[text addSubview:imageView];
```

So how can I add image asynchronously in UITextView?

Comment: What is the method : setImageWithURL:? It might depend on the implementation of method for how are you updating imageView. Moreover be sure to do any UI updates on main thread.

Comment: I don't see an immediate issue with your last block of code. Can you say exactly in what way you "cannot add image asynchronously"? That is, in what way is it not conforming to your expectations?

Answer (score 0):

Use a dispatch :

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       // async UI update here
    });
```